# Google Cloud Messaging from MobileBackendStarter

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-messaging

I am using the google cloud messaging from the mobile backend starter. It seems to work but suddenly  it stops working and says invalid registration/MismatchSenderId and other errors. The issue is since I am still developing the application I have to keep installing a new version every couple of minutes. But sometimes what happens is it clears the orginal id and gets a new one(I think this is the issue) and throws this error. IS there any way to clear the app-engine storage of the sender ids. I can clear the Shared Preference on the android phone but how do I do the same for the app engine?

Comment: Are you changing your application version in the manifest file everytime you test your app?

Comment: No I am not doing anything like that